# "22P02" error occurred when try insert data into Postgres from DataTable

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core

I am trying to create an API to insert data from Oracle to PostgreSQL.

So I will query data from Oracle and stored in a DataTable.

Finally generate insert sql and execute in PostgreSQL.

But I found it would occur error if the table contains numeric or timeStamp type field.

Here are my codes.

I will appreciate for any suggestions.

```
public void Oracle2PG(string fromTable, string toTable)
{
    string pgConn = _configuration.GetValue<string>($"ConnectionStrings:PGConnection");
    string oraConn = _configuration.GetValue<string>($"ConnectionStrings:OracleConnection");

    using (var pgConn = new NpgsqlConnection(sctPgConn))
    using (var oraConn = new OracleConnection(sctOraConn))
    {
        string oraSql = $"select * from {fromTable}";
        var dtOra = GetDatatable(oraSql, "", oraConn);
        string insertSql = GenerateInsertSql(toTable, dtOra);
        pgConn.Execute(insertSql); //occur error "22P02: invalid input syntax for type numeric"
    }
}

private static DataTable GetDatatable(string sql, object para, OracleConnection oraConn)
{
    var res = oraConn.Query(sql, para);
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
    var dtResult = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));

    return dtResult;
}

private static string GenerateInsertSql(string tableName, DataTable dataTable)
{
    var cols = (from DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns select column.ColumnName).ToList();
    string colNames = string.Join(", ", cols);
    string sql = $"Insert into {tableName} ({colNames}) values";
    int cnt = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        cnt += 1;
        sql += $"(";
        var rowValues = row.ItemArray.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToList();
        foreach (string v in rowValues)
        {
            sql += $"'{v}',";
        }
        sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 1);
        if (cnt == dataTable.Rows.Count)
        {
            sql += ") ";
        }
        else
        {
            sql += "), ";
        }
    }
    return sql;
}
```

Comment: To your question add the complete error message text.

Comment: `22P02` is neither a number nor a timestamp. Generating SQL strings by concatenating unchecked input leaves you wide open to SQL injection and unexpected conversion errors. Use parameterized queries instead. The code will be a *lot* shorter, cleaner and faster

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. `22P02` is the error code which per here [Error codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html) translates to 'invalid_text_representation'.  So whatever is being passed is not a properly formatted string for either a `numeric` or `timestamp` field.  Say something like `select ''::timestamp;`

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Why are query results converted to JSON only to be converted back to objects immediately? You could always load query results into a DataTable and store them to a different database table. That's what they were for. There are far faster ways to insert data into a database that individual INSERTs though. In PostgreSQL's case it's through COPY. NpgSQL [already supports this](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The complete error is "22P02: invalid input syntax for type numeric"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have 2 db (oracle and postgre). I have a requirement that copy data from oracle to postgre.

Comment: You need to check the values you are passing in. Best guess it is something like `select ''::numeric;` or `select '1,200'::numeric;` both of which would error out as `invalid input syntax for type numeric: <the value>`. Something in your stack is eating part of the error message as it should also show the actual value causing the issue. Take a look at the Postgres log it will show you more detail.

Comment: @EvaHHHH you don't need JSON for that. The oldest and slowest way would be to load the data into a DataTable and save it with a DataAdapter. All ADO.NET queries return an IDbDataReader. You can load the data into a DataTable with `DataTable.Load`. The *fast* way would be to read the data row-by-row with the data reader  and use NpgSQL's COPY to write it to PostgreSQL.